# how to join totally two different table without having foreign key?

Tags: mysql

i want to join 2 tables that are completely different data. the two table do not have foreign key. i have tried join and other query but i get error. how can i combine the two table?

service table

```
ServiceItemId, ServiceName, ServiceType, ServiceDuration,ServicePrice
```

customer table

```
cust_id
```

expected result:

```
service_id|service_name|serviceType| ServiceDuration|ServicePrice|cust_id
```

this is my code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
        SELECT ServiceItemId, ServiceName, ServiceType, 
                ServiceDuration,ServicePrice, row_number() as num 
        FROM service
     ) AS X
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
                        SELECT custId, row_number() as num 
                        FROM customer
                    ) AS Y
        ON x.num = y.num
```

Comment: You will need something in each tabke that relates customers to contracts or a link table. So you have a link table

Comment: When you ask for help with an error, you should include the exact error message so we don't have to guess. But I would guess you got at least an error about `FULL OUTER JOIN` because MySQL does not support that type of join.

Comment: You also need an `OVER()` clause if you use a window function like `row_number()`.

Comment: Also, I have no idea why you need to get two unrelated result sets as one result set. What's the advantage to doing that if it makes your queries so difficult? Just run two queries.

Comment: Do you just want a `cross join`?